# How to Record Team meeting From as azureBot

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

i am using this code to join and record ongoing meeting, I am able to join the meeting but not able to record it. I am using following code for join and recording.They are asking for compliance policy and third party "callcabinet" for enabling recording. i just enabled calling policy but should i have to get subscription of "callcabinet" also. Please help me in how to record team meeting using my azure bot. Please help me, this is my humble request.

```
 public async Task<Call> JoinScheduledMeeting(string meetingUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                MeetingInfo meetingInfo;
                ChatInfo chatInfo;

                (chatInfo, meetingInfo) = JoinInfo.ParseJoinURL(meetingUrl);

                var call = new Call
                {
                    CallbackUri = $"{this.configuration[Common.Constants.BotBaseUrlConfigurationSettingsKey]}/callback",
                    RequestedModalities = new List<Modality>()
                    {
                        Modality.Audio
                    },
                    MediaConfig = new ServiceHostedMediaConfig
                    {
                    },
                    ChatInfo = chatInfo,
                    MeetingInfo = meetingInfo,
                    TenantId = (meetingInfo as OrganizerMeetingInfo)?.Organizer.GetPrimaryIdentity()?.GetTenantId()
                };

                var statefulCall = await graphServiceClient.Communications.Calls
                        .Request()
                        .AddAsync(call);

                var clientContext = "clientContext-value";
               
               var status = RecordingStatus.NotRecording | RecordingStatus.Failed | RecordingStatus.Recording;

                await graphServiceClient.Communications.Calls[statefulCall.Id]
                    .UpdateRecordingStatus(status, clientContext)
                    .Request()
                    .PostAsync();


                return statefulCall;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is to record an MS Teams meeting, but could you clarify?

Comment: If this is for MS Teams, you may want to check out this option - [record-calls-and-meetings-the-updaterecordingstatus-api-in-microsoft-graph-is-now-generally-available](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/record-calls-and-meetings-the-updaterecordingstatus-api-in-microsoft-graph-is-now-generally-available/). It doesn't feature a BotFramework bot, but the code looks like you could substitute a BF bot in.

Comment: Yes.  this is to record an MS Teams meeting using azure bot. I just want to know how i can record ms team meeting using azure bot+botframework+graph api. There is no any relevant articles which can guide me. i dont want to use any third party for recording. i want to make my own  bot to record ms team meeting. Please help me with this.

Comment: The article you send, i went through that but it did not help. i am using UpdateRecordingStatus as you will see in my code.

Comment: this error message is coming in code:

 Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: 8506
Message: API call not allowed for non-Compliance Recording call
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2022-02-17T04:46:09
 request-id: cc852547-ee8d-44cd-9163-00ff7ba85ae6
 client-request-id: cc852547-ee8d-44cd-9163-00ff7ba85ae6
ClientRequestId: cc852547-ee8d-44cd-9163-00ff7ba85ae6
'

Comment: please provide me the right guidance for recording bot. I am trying to not use any third party vendor for recording. I just want my own bot to do that. Can i do that without any vendor??  Please help me with this.

Comment: I don't know if you are still working on this problem, but I have added the `microsoft-teams` tag. Hopefully, someone from the team supporting SO will see this and can provide more guidance. Unfortunately, I don't know what else you can try.

Comment: @SAURABHMISHRA - are you assigning a recording policy to a set of users? The recording bot will not be allowed to record unless a user with a recording policy joined the call or meeting. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-recording-policy#compliance-recording-policy-assignment-and-provisioning

Comment: we have created the policy which you shared and followed all those steps mentioned in reference url but i have one query in following command:
( New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance -UserPrincipalName cr.instance@contoso.onmicrosoft.com -DisplayName ComplianceRecordingBotInstance -ApplicationId fcc88ff5-a42d-49cf-b3d8-f2e1f609d511).
Can you please let us know what will be the prerequisites for UserPrincipalName(cr.instance@contoso.onmicrosoft.com). Does this domain required policy certification to be enabled first before we do this step.

Comment: @SAURABHMISHRA - Yes. You have to enabled policy certification first.

Comment: Do we have to take vendor certification from Microsoft??

Comment: @SAURABHMISHRA - Yes you have to take vendor certification. For vendor certification send mail to Teamscategorypartner@microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign a recording policy to a set of users.
The recording bot will not be allowed to record unless a user with a recording policy joined the call or meeting.

You have to enabled policy certification first.

You have to take vendor certification. For vendor certification send mail to Teamscategorypartner@microsoft.com.

Doc Reference - [Compliance recording policy assignment and provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-recording-policy#compliance-recording-policy-assignment-and-provisioning)

Comment: I have added the compliance recording policy but still recording is not able to start using azure bot.

Comment: To build your own recording bot, you need to get your solution certified.